# CMake commands in Ant Script

Tags: ant, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file which I want to make by using ant script. Is there a way to give commands for `cmake .` and `make` through ant? I used to have a MakeFile and I had the following command to make it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="sampleProject" default="make">

    <target name="make">
        <exec executable="make" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-f Makefile"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Is it somehow similar to this? Does anyone know how to do it? I am looking for an alternative to [cmakeant](https://code.google.com/p/cmakeant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking CMake from Ant should be analogical. Something like this:

```
  <target name="cmake">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <exec executable="cmake" dir="build" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="../" />
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Basically, it creates `build` subdirectory and invokes CMake from it.  Passing some other CMake arguments should be trivial aswell.

Also, You might check projects like [cmakeant](https://github.com/IainHull/cmakeant), for more sophisticated CMake wrapper.

**NOTE:** invoking `CMake` in source directory is considered to be a bad practice which causes pollution of source subdirectory.